# jquery find abbrev title in table td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following for a while to find text in a TD, and add an image to it... but some of the usernames (text in the td) are too long, so they are cutoff (12 character limit). What I need to do is find the abbrev title, which would be the full text of my winner variable, instead of just text.

```
var winner = "<?php echo $winner; ?>";
if (winner == 0){
} else {
    $("td:contains('<?php echo $winner; ?>')").each(function(){
        $(this).append('<br><br><img src="images/trophy/gold.png" style="width: 40px; margin-left: 30px">');
    });
};
```

Comment: is your $winner php variable at full lenght? So you need to trim it to 12 char to check it against td name?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused - your PHP variable `$winner` is the *abbreviated* 12 character text, or the full text?

Comment: My apologies... the variable is the full text, the 12 character text is just what shows on the table on the site. When hovered over, the abbrev title shows the full text, no matter how long.

Comment: Please include the HTML upon which this code is acting. In other words, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to consider only the first 12 char of the php variable:

```
var winner = "<?php echo $winner; ?>";
var winner_short = "<?php echo substr($winner,0,12); ?>";
if (winner == 0){
} else {
    $("td:contains('"+winner_short+"')").each(function(){
        $(this).append('<br><br><img src="images/trophy/gold.png" style="width: 40px; margin-left: 30px">');
    });
};
```

If this doesn't work you can also do:

```
var winner = "<?php echo $winner; ?>";
if (winner == 0){
} else {
    $("td:contains('<?php echo substr($winner,0,12); ?>')").each(function(){
        $(this).append('<br><br><img src="images/trophy/gold.png" style="width: 40px; margin-left: 30px">');
    });
};
```

Comment: That won't work, since `winner_short` is a variable, and you're including it within the selector. You'd need to concatenate the variable into the selector.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan afaik the first version of the code works well (at least based on my experience. Anyway I added the other version too :)

Comment: The first version should be `$("td:contains('" + winner_short + "')").each...`. That's what I meant.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan whops! I didn't notice I missed the concatenation... thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Ok the second version works... but I did have to change it to `echo substr($winner,0,12);` since I just need the first 12 characters of the text. Update that in your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks! Never even thought about using `substr`... it's the simple things.